# Docker IIS Network Connection to External Network

Tags: iis, docker, docker-for-windows, windows-container

Completely new to Dockers here.

I have a very simple .NET 45 application, that is built on ServiceStack framework. They are mainly APIs web services.

Docker image is built well, container is deployed well and running, no issues. I am using Windows Container (not docker for windows). However, I have one particular web service that is calling a third party API(Legacy), and we are using SOAP client to do that. However, this web services always throw `EndpointNotFound` exception:

> "There was no endpoint listening at https://externalapi.asmx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."

I have read up on Windows NAT issue problem. My gut feeling is that the self contained container is isolated, and hence no external internet connectivity to the outside world. Is there anything that I need to configure on my microsoft/iis image?

My Docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/iis
SHELL ["powershell"]
RUN Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET ; \
    Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45
COPY \ MyAwesomeWebsite
RUN Remove-WebSite -Name 'Default Web Site'
RUN New-Website -Name 'MyAwesomeWebsite' -Port 80 \
    -PhysicalPath 'c:\MyAwesomeWebsite' -ApplicationPool '.NET v4.5'
EXPOSE 80
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check connectivity to external world from your container. Just login to it and try to issue the same call from there. It can be multitude of issues and simplest one can be firewall running on your container host. For me for example unless I stop Mcafee firewall it's not going to work since Mcafee firewall sees traffic coming from 172.x subnet (which container will be run on by default) and it blocks it.